# Why Large Image Path is not set in this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I'm not sure if this is correct or not `$('#bigImage').attr("data-big", LargeImagePath);` But the same statement work fine for `'src'`.

IE. on JSP I get the value of `mediumImagePath` but not large may `.attr` will not use in case of `data-big` so what should I use for `data-big`.

**xyz.js**

```
function getImageDetails(mediumImagePath, LargeImagePath) {
   alert(mediumImagePath+"_______"+mediumImagePath);
   jQuery.ajax({
      type : 'GET',
      url : 'productDetailsPage.do',
      data : {},
      success : function(data) {
         $('#bigImage').attr("src", mediumImagePath);
         $('#bigImage').attr("data-big", LargeImagePath);
         alert(data);           
         $("#productListPage").hide();
         $("#productDetailsPage").show();
      } 
   });
}
```

This is the `div` where where I'm trying to set those values:

**Abc.Jsp**

```
<div class="view-product">
  <img id="bigImage" class="fancybox" src=""
       data-big="images/home/suitlarge.jpg" />
    <h3>ZOOM</h3>
</div>
```

**Productdiv.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<div>

    <c:forEach items="${products}" var="products">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                <div class="single-products">
                    <div class="productinfo text-center">
                        <img src="${products.smallImage}" onclick="getImageDetails('${products.mediumImage}', '${products.largeImage}');" alt="${products.productId}productImage" />
                        <h2>${products.allPrice}</h2>
                        <p>${products.name}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to
                                Wishlist</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

Please help and explain what's wrong.

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: How do you call, `getImageDetails` and what is the expected results. The only attribute that has a real effect on the image is the `src` attribute. Anything else has to be handled manually.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what the problem is?  What are you asking for help with?

Comment: I use src attribute to set the medium image and when i click on that med image i want yo open the large image of the same content  on a popup

Comment: refer from image i added

Comment: Are you using `#bigImage` on all images? If you are, **ID** should be unique for each element.

Comment: Do you have a public URL of your project? It will much easier for us to help you that way.

Comment: @Vucko I am using  #bigImage in only one image tag on 'Abc.jsp' that will open for a particular image click on 'productdiv.jsp'

Comment: @MoshFeu no .. i don't have a  public URL of this, I'm doing this for practice so i'm running this on local host

Comment: Try `rel` instead of `data-big`. At least `rel` is real attribute.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to access the `data` attribute you should use `data` and NOT `attr`

So your code should be something like `$('#bigImage').data("big", LargeImagePath);`

**Here's a complete example:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var big = $("#bigImage").data("big");
            alert(big);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="bigImage" class="fancybox" src="" data-big="images/home/suitlarge.jpg" />
</body>
```